# Iphone - Switch App ID and Developer Account

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I started building an app under an individual developer account.
In preparing to beta and release this I'm switching over to a new company account.

I'm trying to prepare a checklist of the things I will need to update in order to move the project over to the new account.

- Install new development certificate
  and profile
- Change bundle identifier
  in the -info.plist to match the new
  app ID
- In project build settings change code signing identify

Appreciate any words of wisdom from others who may have gone through a similar process or pointers to other questions that address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my checklist in addition to your list:

- Change Version of your app to 1.0 in case if this is your first time you submit the app. If it's an update make sure it has higher version number than the one on app store
- Add Code Signing Entitlement file to the project
- Remove debug code like NSLog
- Build the App store distribution. Actually there is a guide for this https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action
- Remember to keep the dSYM file that generated along with the .app file so that you can symbolicate the crash log later.
- I don't know if that happen to everyone. But before you zip your binary file (.app file) make sure that the file name of the binary file don't have any special character, best to leave it as alphabet only, since it does not affect anything.
- Zip your binary file
- Submit to appstore using app uploader utility.

That what I remember. Correct me If I'm wrong. Hope this help:).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to clear your Mac user account's Keychain of all old certificates (or use a different Mac User account), clear the Xcode Organizer of all old provisions and then quit and restart Xcode, and delete all old provisions off of your device (Edit: you can keep the old provisions if they are named differently and are for different app IDs).

Also make sure to register the new app ID in the provisioning portal and create and download new mobileprovisions.